# Biblatex using polyglossia language setting

Tags: biblatex, languages, polyglossia, package-options

I noticed `biblatex` uses the language option passed to `polyglossia` first, before acknowledging the option passed to it via the `language = <language>` option.

Here is the MWE that illustrates the problem.

```
\documentclass[slovene,a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[language=slovene, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\setdefaultlanguage{slovenian}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{slovene}{slovene-apa}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Cite here \parencite{aksin}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The example compiles fine, but how can I avoid the warning given:

> Package biblatex Warning: Language 'slovenian' not supported.
>
> (biblatex)      Using fallback language 'slovene' on input
> line 25.

Comment: You can't really avoid this currently as `biblatex` will always try to automatically detect the language from the default polyglossia/babel language first. This is an annoying artefact due to biblatex and polyglossia naming languages differently. I hope in the future that polyglossia and babel can standardise on BCP47 locale names (biber already supports these and maps internally to the polyglossia/babel names).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @PLK. Care to write this as an answer I can accept? I would say it is indeed (a temporary) answer anyhow.

Comment: @Fato39 I tried your MWE and it compiles indeed, but the problem with language naming incompatibility persists. The bibliography strings like `andothers` or `pages` still lack translation into Slovene/Slovenian language (sl-SI). **PS:** What is the `\DeclareLanguageMapping` for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consulting with `biblatex` maintainer Philip Kime, I give you his solution:

```
\DeclareLanguageMapping{slovenian}{slovene}
```

makes `biblatex` and `biber` understand that both language identifiers refer to the same `sl-SI` language (see package documentation, as @moewe suggests). Hence the bibliography strings like `andothers` or `pages` successfully get their respective translations - which was *not* the case when I compiled the MWE provided in the question.

Regarding the warnings in the log file, I would confirm that they cannot be avoided. That is, until the `slovenian` identifier is hard-coded into `biblatex` as a synonym for `slovene`, just like `UKenglish` is for `british`.

Answer (score 1):

`biblatex` will always try to automatically detect the language from the default polyglossia/babel language first. The problem you are seeing is an annoying artefact due to `biblatex` and `polyglossia` naming languages differently. I hope in the future that `polyglossia` and `babel` can standardise on BCP47 locale names (`biber` already supports these and maps internally to the `polyglossia`/`babel` names).